# Python XML parsing - use of "is not None"

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse an XML document which contains an optional field  in python 2.7.9 using xml.etree.ElementTree.

When I use the following loop:

```
summary = curTag.find('summary')
if summary is not None: 
    summary = curTag.find('summary').text.encode('utf8')
    summary = summary.replace("'","'||chr(39)||'")
    summary = summary[:4000]
```

I get the the error - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

However it works when i use:

```
summary = curTag.find('summary')
if summary: 
    summary = curTag.find('summary').text.encode('utf8')
    summary = summary.replace("'","'||chr(39)||'")
    summary = summary[:4000]
```

However, I get a warning - 
FutureWarning: The behavior of this method will change in future versions.  Use specific 'len(elem)' or 'elem is not None' test instead.
  if summary.text is not None:

I've just moved to python from R and am trying to figure out why this is happening.

---

Adding the exact error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('D:/XML_Parsev1.0.py', wdir='D:')

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 601, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 66, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

File "D:/XML_Parsev1.0.py", line 69, in 
    summary = curTag.find('summary').text.encode('utf8')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: can you show us the exact error messages you get?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but what is the difference between the two versions of your code?

Comment: And the XML in question, while you're at it.

Comment: Looked through the XML. (Cannot share it here.) - it seems to have just a tag <summary/> and without an opening. Possibly that is the cause of error. Is there a way to resolve this instead of using - "if summary:"

Comment: What' s the diff between code parts?They are exactly same

Comment: rechecked this.. editing error. I've updated the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your summary tag is empty hence `curTag.find('summary').text` is equal to `None`.

You can't encode `None` because `None` is not a string.

Here's a quick workaround:

```
if summary: 
    summary = (curTag.find('summary').text or '').encode('utf8')
```

This works because if `summary.text` is `None`, then `or` statement will return an empty string which is perfectly encodable.